# OSX Terminal Command To Make App Run At Startup

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I need to use a terminal command to set an app to run at startup. I know I've done it before, but it may have been using Applescript. Every time I attempt to Google my issue, I get only results for "how to run a certain terminal command at startup." I need to SETUP AN APP TO RUN AT STARTUP USING A TERMINAL COMMAND. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The MacOS terminal supports the `open` command, which simulates a double click on whatever comes after it. For example `open /path/to/Applications/OpenThis.app`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. Start Script Editor

   - Create new document and paste following line of code:

     ```
     do shell script "open -a Safari"
     ```
   - Save it as follows:

     - Save As: *LoginScript*
     - Where: *Applications*
     - File Format: *Application*
2. Go to *System Preferences* -> *Users & Groups* -> *Login Items*

   Click "`+`" to add *Applications* -> *"LoginScript"*